# Can I run setup.py which uses setuptools with a flag and just get the requirements?

Tags: pip, setuptools, pypi

Can I run setup.py which uses setuptools with a flag and just get the requirements ?

Comment: I believe there is no such command, but you can look into `setup.py` manually. Dependencies are declared via `install_requires` keyword. Packages required for setup script to run are declared via `setup_requires`

Comment: figured as much. here is what I am making to cope with this for now:
https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/python-dependency-verifier

Answer (score 0):

For now I can't find a real solution for this, so here is a python script I made to cope with this issue based on string search:
https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/python-dependency-verifier